# Vuetify - How to highlight row on click in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to highlight the selected row in v-data-table? i tried to modified the data by adding flag variable `selected` in the [Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xogRKW?editors=1010)

In the above example click on a row will be highlighted by adding class called primary. If it is a static data it is working fine, but if it is dynamic data like getting data from API, the data in the data table will always be refreshed, if i change the pagination and sort and all.

For example, in my case, if i sort the column the data will come from the API and data in the v-data-table will be refreshed with sorted data, in this case it is very hard to maintain that `selected` flag each and every time when ever the data changes. Is there any other way to highlight a selected row?

Comment: Do you have unique id on every row? If you do, you can store list of selected rows' ids, then do select row on repopulate `v-data-table`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution does not work because the `selected` property is added to the data when you click on a row, but when data is reloaded then the data without a `selected` property replaces the old data.

So to make it work:
- add an `id` field to each item in the list of desserts
- add an `selectedId` with default value -1 to your data
- change the line of code in method `activerow` to `this.selectedId = item.id;`
- change the class attribute in the `<tr>` to `:class="{'primary': props.item.id===selectedId}"`

If on reload *only* your list of desserts changes, and the new list contains an item with the same id as selected before, then the same row should become selected.

I forked the codepen example to show you how this works:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrWjxQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 22):

```
<v-data-table @click:row="rowClick" item-key="name" single-select ...

methods: {
    rowClick: function (item, row) {      
      row.select(true);
      //item.name - selected id
    }
}

<style>
  tr.v-data-table__selected {
    background: #7d92f5 !important;
  }
</style>
```

or

```
<style scoped>
  /deep/ tr.v-data-table__selected {
    background: #7d92f5 !important;
  }
</style>
```

Example 
https://codepen.io/nicolai-nikolai/pen/GRgLpNY

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give context to the code (I assume that the first line is in the HTML, but where?). The best way is to give a code snippet. Here is a good guide o nhow to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Duplicate answer. Please don't copy-paste the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582412/how-to-pull-data-from-a-vuetify-datatable-selected-row/59933510#59933510) on multiple questions. This duplicated answer doesn't add any value to the question, and the existing accepted answer.

Comment: I found this answer first and it is better alternative than other ways of handling row click especially on Vuetify 2.0

Comment: I like this solution. Works well for my needs.

Comment: Use `::v-deep` in newer Versions instead of `/deep/` to override Vuetify stylings.

Answer (score 0):

How to make the row clickable is allready explained by others but not how to toggle the row selection. The selection state can be checked through `isSelected` and then set accordingly.

To style the selected row properly you need something more to take into account: the dark and light theme and the `hover` css pseudo class - which is overridden through the `important` tag so we need to restyle it.

[Check out the Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/Hexodus/pen/ExKGWBe)

```
methods: {
    rowClick: function (item, row) {      
      let selectState = (row.isSelected) ? false : true;
      row.select(selectState);
    }
}


<style>
    .theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected {
        background: #f5c17d70 !important;
    }
    .theme--dark.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected {
        background: #a17b4970 !important;
    }
    .theme--dark.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected:hover {
        background: #a17b49c2 !important;
    }
    .theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected:hover {
        background: #ffd296d2 !important;
    }
</style>
```