# How to highlight rows in v-data-table on click in Vuetify (version >= 2.0)?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use a `v-data-table` to manage emails. User can click on a row and a popup appears with the email details.

**What I want to have:** 
 
I want to have rows marked as "readed" (so css bold/not-bold) after these rows were clicked.

**Problem:** 
 
I already found some examples here (but only for older Vuetify versions): [Vuetify - How to highlight row on click in v-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686652/vuetify-how-to-highlight-row-on-click-in-v-data-table)

This example (and all other examples I've found) use extended code for `v-data-table` - like:

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:items="props">
    <tr @click="activerow(props.item)" :class="{'primary': props.item.id===selectedId}">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

So extended code is:

```html
<template v-slot:items="props">
  <tr @click="activerow(props.item)" :class="{'primary': props.item.id===selectedId}">
    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

However since I use Vutify version 2 the

`<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">`
and
`<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">`
inside
`<v-data-table>`
seem to be ignored.

Vuetify 2 provides some new slots, but I have not yet find out how to use them for this example.

Can anyone provide an example for Vuetify >= 2.0?
Believe me, there is no one for higher versions available yet - not on any development environment like CodePen or JSFiddle etc.

Comment: You might be able to use the `click:row` event, but if you want to persist the clicked state when you refresh the page, you might need to use the v-slot solution.

Comment: Hi Flame, i use also `click:row` but without an solution yet. It would be great if you could provide a workable excample in CodePen.

Comment: Try something along the lines of: `@click="$event.target.classList.add('clicked')"` to add a `clicked` class to the element you just clicked

Answer (score 10):

For me it workes with Vuetify 2.X by replacing the table body (`v-slot:body`) and define the `tr` and `td` manually. It helps to study the [Slot Example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#slots).

This way it is possible to add the click event and set the css class like this:

```
<template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" @click="selectItem(item)" :class="{'selectedRow': item === selectedItem}">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

(Side note: This way you can not use the event `click:row` on the `v-data-table` anymore. Because it does not get fired by overwriting the row... But defining `@click` directly on `tr` works nicely too.)

In method `selectItem` we save the item in a data field `selectedItem`.

```
data () {
  return {
    selectedItem: null,
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
    selectItem (item) {
      console.log('Item selected: ' + item.name)
      this.selectedItem = item
    }
}
```

CSS class we set when the row is clicked. So background changes and text gets **bold**:

```
<style scoped>
.selectedRow {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is not a great solution. When you define custom header, item or body slots it will completely take over the internal rendering of the component which will require you to re-implement functionalities such as selection and expansion.

Answer (score 4):

I have added method `selectRow` that receives an item, and adds `isSelected` property to it. Then in `template` I assign class `.primary` if item has property `isSelected`.

**Notice**: this methods also removes `isSelected` property from previous selected item. so that only one `<tr>` can be highlighted at the same time.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    selectRow(item) {
      // remove isSelected from already selected item
      // const prevItem = this.desserts.find(dessert => dessert.isSelected);
      // if (prevItem) this.$delete(prevItem, 'isSelected');
      this.$set(item, "isSelected", true)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.primary,
.primary:hover {
  /** avoid using !important, added just for example**/
  background-color: red !important;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:items="props">
        <tr @click="selectRow(props.item)" :class="{ 'primary': props.item.isSelected }">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Java, your example totaly works fine with Vuetify 1.5 but unfortunately not with the newer versions > 2.0. That is what I try to find out - how it works with the newest versions.

Comment: @Varathron, I can supplement my answer using Vuetify `2.x`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old question, but you can use vuetify's `item-class` and `@click:row` properties to handle row click and set custom row class.