# Perform operation on data table row in Vue child component once async data is loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, datatable, vuejs2, watch

I have child component that utilizes a Vuetify [v-data-table](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), and when the page that displays this component and its parent are displayed, I want to have the first item in the list highlighted (the data for the item is displayed above it in the parent component, too). I also want to have the row highlighted when it is selected and the data for that row is displayed in the parent.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686652/vuetify-how-to-highlight-row-on-click-in-v-data-table), I have the second part working fine, and the first part (highlighting the first row on initial display) working, but only to an extent.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      :key="tableKey"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      disable-initial-sort
      rowKey
    >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <tr @click="clicked(props.item)" :class="{'secondary': props.item[rowKey]===selectedCode}">
        <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
          <BaseTableColumn
            :item="props.item"
            :index="header.value"
            :format="header.format"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseTable',
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    search: String,
    tableKey: String,
    rowKey: String,
  },
  data: () => ({
    pagination: {
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      totalItems: -1,
    },
    selectedCode: -1,
    itemsYN: false,
  }),
  components: {
    BaseTableColumn: () => import('@/components/base/BaseTableColumn'),
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(row) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
      this.$set(row, 'selected', true);
      this.$emit('rowClick', row);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Select the first item in the list of items (if there are any)
    // and highlight it.
    if (this.items.length > 0) {
      this.selectedCode = this.items[0][this.rowKey];
      this.$set(this.items[0], 'selected', true);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

where this component is called from the parent like so:

```
<BaseTable
  :headers="headers"
  :items="alerts"
  :search="search"
  rowKey="messageId"
  @rowClick="rowClick"
/>
```

As of now, I have the code for the initial highlighting in the `mounted()` hook. This works fine when all of the `items` data is already available at mount time, but if the call to get the data takes longer and isn't loaded until it's past that point in the lifecycle, then I don't get the highlighting. The same is true if I used the `created()` hook

My thought was to watch the `items` prop, and once it is filled, call the highlighting code, like so:

```
  watch: {
    items(val) {
      if (this.items.length > 0) {
        this.highlightFirst(val)
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(row) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
      this.$set(row, 'selected', true);
      this.$emit('rowClick', row);
    },
    highlightFirst(items) {
      this.selectedCode = this.items[0][this.rowKey];
      this.$set(this.items[0], 'selected', true);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Select the first item in the list of items (if there are any)
    // and highlight it.
    if (this.items.length > 0) {
      this.highlightFirst(this.items);
    }
  },
```

but since `items` is updated whenever a row is selected, this overrides the `clicked()` method, and so the first item is highlighted, not the one that was clicked on.

Since this component is a child of 14 components, I would like to handle this in this component instead of adding a passed in prop from all the parents to indicate when the data is loaded. How can I highlight the first row on initial page load, waiting for async data to passed in, without stomping on the `clicked()` method when an individual row is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable where you can store `true` when `click` the button and set `false` when entering the `watch`

```
data: (){
      return {
          fromClick: true;
      }
  },
  watch: {
    items(val) {
      if (!fromClick) {
        this.highlightFirst();
      }
      this.fromClick = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(row) {
      this.fromClick = true;
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.hightlightRow(row);
      this.$emit('rowClick', row);
    },
    highlightFirst() {
      if (this.items.length > 0) {
        this.hightlightRow(this.items[0]);
      }
    },
    hightlightRow(row) {
      this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
      this.$set(row, 'selected', true);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Select the first item in the list of items (if there are any)
    // and highlight it.
    this.highlightFirst();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this in a simpler way with the following code.

```
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    search: String,
    tableKey: String,
    rowKey: String,
  },
  data: () => ({
    ...
    selectedCode: -1,
  }),  
  methods: {
    clicked(row) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
      this.$set(row, 'selected', true);
      this.$emit('rowClick', row);
    },
    highlightFirst(items) {
      this.selectedCode = this.items[0][this.rowKey];
      this.$set(this.items[0], 'selected', true);
    },
  },
  updated() {
    if (this.selectedCode === -1 && && (typeof this.items === 'object') && this.items.length > 0) {
      this.highlightFirst(this.items);
    }
  },
```

Once `this.selectedCode` has a value after `highlightFirst()` is run, nothing happens in `update()`, and the `clicked()` method works as it should when a row is clicked.